# Import with Magmi broken after Patch 1533 5344 on 1.9.x

Tags: magento, magmi

I've successfully patched Magento but after this update Magmi seems broken.
On a dev environment I'm trying to import a correct CSV file with a lot of simple and configurable products.
The simple ones are ok, the configurable ones and the images for both are completely broken. The simple SKUs are associated togheter in what it seems to be a  completely random way.
Do you guys have encountered the same problem or do you have any advice to spare?
Thanks!

Comment: One of the issues patched was a database sql injection issue. You will need to go contact the Magmi support (github) and ask there if there were any problems created by the 5344 patch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what this patches is the reason of issue.

PATCH_SUPEE-1533 change next files:

1. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
2. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php

PATCH_SUPEE-5344 change next files:

1. app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
2. app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
3. app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
4. app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
5. lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

This changes can't affect on Magmi import process.

Comment: Mysql injection patch in 5344 could cause an issue on the origin check with Magmi.